# How can i fix cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev)

Tags: python

I wanna make image to sketch using `opencv-python`. I already installed the package but why there is still error?

```
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: What is the error you see? Can you paste?

Comment: it says:
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall OpenCV:
In terminal like this, if you using Jupiter put it like !pip...

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python
```

This just worked for me.

Also, make sure, you have the right path for the file, and used
`image= cv2.imread("path")` to convert the image into the numpy array, so cv2 can work with it.

Also, your command only converts images into the shades of gray. If you want pure black-and-white:

```
threshold_img = cv2.threshold(gray_img, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```